# NAS does not reconnect to network after router reboot

Tags: networking, home-networking, nas, synology

My Synology NAS does not reconnect to the network when the router reboots or when Internet goes down and then comes back. I am connected over ethernet and the network light is on but I cannot ping the NAS or access it through the webpage.

What could be the reason for this?

Edit 2018-05-23: Added bounty. This is a weird issue. All the other devices in my network (hard-wired or wireless) reconnect to the network/Internet after the Internet comes back up but my NAS does not respond when I try to ping the machine (ping 192.168.1.xxx or ping NAS)

Comment: What do you do to make the NAS connect anew? Power cycle it? disconnect and reconnect the network cable? or what?

Comment: Is the IP setup statically or through DHCP?

Comment: Have you followed [this guideline](https://www.synology.com/en-global/knowledgebase/DSM/help/DSM/AdminCenter/connection_routerconf) and which options did you choose in the router setup screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved my issue. I had my NAS' MAC address assigned a static IP in my router. In the NAS, I had the IP obtained by DHCP. I changed this to a Static IP (same IP in the router) and this  fixed my issue.

Must have been an issue of same IP on network or something but anyway, now the NAS will automatically reconnect to network if it ever loses connection my router.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably dhcp renew expiration time, you can try to reduce the value on your DHCP server to force Synology to request it more quickly.